# Calling convention error with DLL

Tags: c, gcc, dll, shared-libraries

I'm building a DLL with MinGW, 32 bit mode for an application (PCSX) I have the source for. I'm following the guideline of another modules source.

The error produced is:

> Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

PSEgetLibName is called fine, and returns the proper result.
PADinit throws the above error.

```
// sucess, everything configured, and went OK.
#define PSE_PAD_ERR_SUCCESS         0
```

main.h

```
long PADinit(long flags);
```

main.c

```
long PADinit(long flags) {
    return PSE_PAD_ERR_SUCCESS;
}
char *PSEgetLibName(void) {
    return _("PSX-U");
}
```

Makefile:

```
# Build for Windows under MinGW
#MINGWDBG= -DDEBUG -O0
MINGWDBG= -DNDEBUG -O2
#MINGWOPT= -W -Wall -mthreads -Wl,--subsystem,console $(MINGWDBG) -DHAVE_STDINT
MINGWOPT= -W -Wall -mthreads -Wl,--subsystem,windows $(MINGWDBG)
mingw:
    windres win32\res.rc win32\res.o
    gcc $(MINGWOPT) mongoose.c main.c -lws2_32 \
        -shared -Wl,--out-implib=$(PROG).lib -o $(PROG).dll
    gcc $(MINGWOPT) mongoose.c main.c win32\res.o -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 \
        -o $(PROG).exe
```

I tried declaring the function with `__stdcall` and `__cdecl`, as it seemed to matter for this error, but it won't change the result.

Edit:
Code calling:

plugins.h

```
typedef long (CALLBACK* PADinit)(long);
...
extern PADinit             PAD1_init;
```

plugins.c

```
    ret = PAD1_init(1);
```

Complete source code here (for PCSX):
http://pcsxr.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Comment: What code is calling that function?

Comment: Added the calling code, although nothing fancy. The complete source is also available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that mingw needs to be passed a parameter to the linker (-Wl,--add-stdcall-alias) and using __stdcall finally solved the matter!

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_DLL

Answer (score 2):

You should stick with the `CALLBACK` macro, as it is done in the plugins header file and in the other plugins in the source code you refer to.

It expands to `__attribute__((__stdcall__))` with mingw/GCC 4.5. Put it both in the header and in the implementation file.

```
long CALLBACK PADinit(long flags);
```

```
long CALLBACK PADinit(long flags) {
    return PSE_PAD_ERR_SUCCESS;
}
```

You should annotate all the callback functions like that, whether or not they appear to be working.

Comment: Does placing before or after the returntype matter? I tried mostly any combination with dllexport, __stdcall__, extern and am still lost.

Comment: Shouldn't matter, you could place it after the function argument list too. Make sure nothing is `undef`ing CALLBACK (or defining it to an empty thing).